# Simultaneously see Eevee and Cycles renderings

Tags: rendering

Since the light rendering is not the same depending on whether we use Cycles or Eevee, I would like to easily compare this difference on a small scene.

Is it possible to display simultaneously Eevee and Cycles rendering in two different windows instead of having to constantly switch the render engine?

Comment: If by "different windows" you mean a second Blender instance, then yes, this should be possible (depending on the specs of your hardware). You can also open the same scene on two different Computers. You still have to reload the file manually in the second instance after editing and saving it in the first instance.

Comment: I meant in two different areas in one Blender Window. I can indeed use a second Blender instance, but I was wondering if it's possible in a single window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such functionality in Blender 2.80. Only one rendering engine can be selected at a time in one instance of Blender. It might not be very practical to attempt running two render engines on the same hardware at the same time in 3d Viewports. If you wanted to view the render previews side by side I think the easiest solution would be to make screenshots of the viewport. You could look into some software that may make the process easier.

I could recommend looking into this nice free program called PureRef - I use it myself and it works perfectly for this when the interior designers I work with want to compare variations of some designs side by side in real-time. It makes it extremely simple to make a screenshot and paste it right on top of the screen and then crop it with it's shortcuts (<kbd>c</kbd> + left click) and keep it there for a while while working.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe an old question but worth mentioning that YES, it is indeed possible. Though may be seen as a workaround:

First place all your settings as you'd like them with **Eevee** set as your renderer. This includes activating AO, screenspace reflections, irradiance/reflection objects etc. Any setting that is relevant to Eevee basically. This doesn't include lights.

*NOTE: HDRI will be independant from Cycles world settings if you're using an irradiance object to bake the lighting.*

When you have it all set, split the window to have a second 3D view, then switch to **Cycles** as your renderer. In the one view set the shading mode to **rendered** (shortcut: Z) which will be Cycles, and set the other shading mode to **material preview** for Eevee.
In the material preview window, make sure that the extra options "Scene lights" and "Scene world" are checked.
[image: Cycles and Eevee settings]